# Выдает ошибку json.decoder.JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, json

Я новичок, еще только учу Python, учу самостоятельно по книге "Изучаем Python" Eric Matthes. Прохожу 10 главу, упражнение 11:

---

**Любимое число:** напишите программу, которая запрашивает у пользователя его любимое число. Воспользуйтесь функцией **json.dump()** для сохранения этого числа в файле.
Напишите другую программу, которая читает это значение и выводит сообщение: «Я знаю
ваше любимое число! Это _____».

---

**Написал код:**

```
import json

filename = "best_number.json"

try:
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        bn = json.load(f)
except FileNotFoundError:
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        b_n = input("Введите ваше любимое число.")
        json.dump(b_n, f)
else:
    print(f'Я знаю ваше любимое число! Это {bn}!')
```

---

**Выдает ошибку:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\X550CC\Desktop\python\10\9.py", line 7, in <module>
    bn = json.load(f)
  File "C:\Users\X550CC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Users\X550CC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\X550CC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\X550CC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я сделал не так.

Comment: Вы в файле `best_number.json` записали что-то некорректное. Если файл пустой, то это тоже некорректно

Comment: Запустил ваш фрагмент кода на python3.8.10 - такой ошибки не встретил.
Уточните пожалуйста, что вы вводите при запуске и как вы запускаете ваш код.

Comment: файла не существует, его должен по идее должен создать код сам. Пишу код в Sublime Text, запускаю через cmd. При вводе ничего не ввожу, сразу выдает ошибку.

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `except FileNotFoundError:` на `except (FileNotFoundError, json.JSONDecodeError):`.

Comment: Cпасибо огромное, помогло!